Incorrect value assignment
I've been struggling with this problem for a very long time! Below is a part of the code that should calculate the minimum number of lots to enter a position. The problem is that the min_position value is incorrectly assigned to the qty_position variable both during the first assignment and subsequently.
Logs:
[2024-09-29T23:31:29.957+03:00]: Final qty_position value: 122
[2024-09-29T23:31:29.957+03:00]: Calculated min_position value: 1357
[2024-09-29T23:31:29.957+03:00]: Manual calculation: 1357.4414942716

Code:
// Get the current price of the instrument
entry = 21 // Number of entries into the position
current_price = float(close)
calculated_min_position = (deposit * leverage) / (current_price * entry)
min_position = math.floor(calculated_min_position)

// Global variables
var float prev_deposit = na
var int prev_leverage = na
var int qty_position = na  

// Force initialization of qty_position on first call
if na(qty_position)
    qty_position := min_position
    prev_deposit := deposit
    prev_leverage := leverage

// Update qty_position 
if deposit != prev_deposit or leverage != prev_leverage
    qty_position := min_position
    prev_deposit := deposit
    prev_leverage := leverage

// Logging values ​​for checking
log.info("Final value of qty_position: " + str.tostring(qty_position))
log.info("Calculated value of min_position: " + str.tostring(min_position))
log.info("Manual calculation: " + str.tostring(deposit * leverage / current_price / entry))

Tried many options, no result

With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question.
what is var deposit ? what is var leverage ?

@Gu5tavo71
deposit = input.float(10, title="Deposit ", minval=1, group = "POSITION CALCULATION", inline = "Position") // Deposit
leverage = input.int(10, title="Leverage ", minval=1, maxval = 120, group = "POSITION CALCULATION", inline = "Position") // Leverage
